# Check if set is dense in $([0,1],d)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> I need to check if the set $\{\frac{k}{2^n},k,n ∈ N\}$ is dense in the metric space $([0, 1],d)$, where $d(x, y) = |x − y|$

I think it's not possible to find a sequence of elements of the set that has $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, but don't know how to show it formally

Answer (score 2):

Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and any number $x\in[0,1]$.

There is $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{2^N}<\varepsilon$.

It is obvious that $$[0,1]=\bigcup_{k=0}^{2^N-1}\left[\frac{k}{2^N},\frac{k+1}{2^N}\right],$$
so there is at least one number $K=1,\dots,2^N-1$ such that $x\in\left[\frac{K}{2^N},\frac{K+1}{2^N}\right]$.

Hence $d(K/2^N,x)\le \frac{1}{2^N}<\varepsilon$.